# Spring cloud with Eureka, Oauth2 and zuul

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am trying to configure the sample https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/tree/master/oauth2/ui to use eureka for the userAuthorizationUri part but with no luck so far. my oauth2 server is registered via eureka

```
   server:
      port: ${PORT:${SERVER_PORT:0}}
    debug:
    security:
      user:
        password: none
    zuul:
      routes:
        resource:
          path: /resource/**
          url: http://localhost:9000/resource
        user:
          path: /user/**
          serviceId: authentication-service/uaa/user

    spring:
      application:
        name: ui-service
      oauth2:
        sso:
          home:
            secure: false
            path: /,/**/*.html
        client:
          accessTokenUri: http://authentication-service/uaa/oauth/token
          userAuthorizationUri: http://authentication-service/uaa/oauth/authorize
          clientId: acme
          clientSecret: acmesecret
        resource:
          serviceId: ${PREFIX:}resource
          jwt:
            keyValue: |
              -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
              MYKEY
              -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    logging:
      level:
        org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    eureka:
      instance:
        metadataMap:
          instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.int(10000)}}
      client:
        serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: http://localhost:8888/eureka/
```

Comment: "no luck" is not much of a description of the problem.  Any more details on what is happening?  `authentication-service/uaa/user` doesn't look like a valid serviceId, btw.

Comment: I think he's trying to use Ribbon to contact the auth server. We don't support that out of the box AFAIK.

Comment: I am just trying to contact the auth server through the eureka server by its registered name which is in my case authentication-service. @Dave are you going to support this in the future? seems logical to me if all the services are going to communicate through Discovery no?

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for the hint I have now got at least the resource service through eureka 

`zuul:
  routes:
    resource:
      path: /resource/**
      serviceId: oauth2-resource
      stripPrefix: false
`

Comment: You can raise an issue in github if you like. But apps have to send a redirect to browsers with the authorization endpoint, so it has to be converted somewhere. It won't be trivial at all.